# Is there a drawback of calling more than one function in a ng-click directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

We are calling two functions in a single ng-click directive, is there any gotcha that we should be aware of?

```
<button type="button" ng-click="func1(); func2();">Click</button>
```

We could also call a single function that calls the two function instead:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="func1()">Click</button>

$scope.func1(){
  func2();
}

$scope.func2(){
 //something
}
```

Comment: Use one function and keep logic in controller where it belongs. Easier to see logic when reading controller code and easier to refactor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no drawback of calling more than one function inside ng-click, but we have to ignore it most of the time because it's not good practice.

You can achieve this by calling a function inside another function.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="func1(); func2(); func3();">Click</button>
```

So here func1 will call first, then func2 and func3.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't make a difference, both of them works as well as another (and in my opinion better) option

```
<button type="button" ng-click="clickAction()">Click</button>

$scope.clickAction = function() {
    $scope.func1();
    $scope.func2();
};
```

Comment: Why so brother, is there any problem with the first approach? @AlexD

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya It's good to have your directives (e.g. `ng-click`) just provide the "glue" between the view and your controller, and have the controller take care of the actual logic. From that perspective, I think it's better to have just one function in `ng-click` and have the handler do whatever you need.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Create a third method that wrap both methods. Advantage here is that you put less logic in your template

Answer (score 1):

Calling two functions in one ng-click is a bad practice. What happens when you decide you want to add a third function? What if you only want the second function to happen when a certain condition has been met? Putting more logic than is necessary in your presentation code is poor separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

yes, first approach is correct. `ng-click` ask a valid AngularJS `expression` and evaluate the same, doesn't matter it's a single or multimple function or any other expression like `"anyVar = 'Button Clicked'"`

So these below examples are correct

```
<button type="button" ng-click="func1(); func2();">Click</button>
```

or

```
<button type="button" ng-click="anyVar = 'Button Clicked'; index++;">Click</button>
```

Comment: I think this is correct.
It works because `ng-click` evaluate `AngularJS expression` inside this, not a `function` only.

Comment: what does *"below is correct"* mean? Not much of an answer

Comment: I did...it was this answer that is very vague and doesn't specificlly answer the question

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with both ways, but I would declare only 1 function in `$scope` and another 2 functions only in JS:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="func3();">Click</button>

func1() {
  // something
}

func2() {
  // something
}

$scope.func3 = function() {
  func1();
  func2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the approaches are correct. But instead we can have those two functions `func1()` and `func2()` as JS functions instead of `scope` functions and call them both inside your new scope function using `ng-click`.

HTML code:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="click()">Button</button>
```

Controller code:

```
function func1() {
    // func1 code goes here
}

function func2() {
    // func2 code goes here
}

$scope.click = function() {
    func1();
    func2();
}
```

This implementation has a couple of advantages compared to adding two functions on `ng-click`

- First is, it reduces the number of watchers since we have only **one** `scope` function whereas adding two functions to `ng-click` requires you to define both the functions in `scope`.
- Second is, if running your `func2()` is conditional i.e, it is dependent on output of `func1()`, you can decide whether to run `func2()` or not.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no drawback, but it is not good practice... And there is no difference whether you are calling function inside ng-click or inside another function in controller. And if you are calling function inside ng-click then they will call in sequence in which they written there.

For example : func1() will call first then func2()...